# ios: For loop goes to infinite

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsarray, nsdictionary

Whats wrong in this code, as I am trying to get NSDictionary objects from NSArray of NSDictionary Objects but it goes into infinite loop.

```
- (void)updateFieldsWithData:(NSArray *)items {
    // NSLog(@"updateFieldsWithData (%d)", [items count]);

    for ( NSDictionary * item in items ) { // add rows to the item table
        [tfPhoneNumber setText:[item valueForKey:kPhoneNumberKey]];
        [tfFirstName setText:[item valueForKey:kFirstNameKey]];
        [tfLastName setText:[item valueForKey:kLastNameKey]];
        [tfEmailAddress setText:[item valueForKey:kEmailKey]];
        [tfStreet setText:[item valueForKey:kStreetKey]];
        [tfCity setText:[item valueForKey:kCityKey]];
        [tfState setText:[item valueForKey:kStateKey]];
        [tfZipCode setText:[item valueForKey:kZipCodeKey]];
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can it be that the error is somewhere else and your updateFieldsWithData-method is called multiple times?

Comment: Where is `updateFieldsWithData:` being called from? The data in the console suggests that `for` loop will only execute once since `items` only contains one item. It suggests that `updateFieldsWithData:` is being called repeatedly.

Comment: Also, why is item nil at this point?

Comment: Sometimes `NSLog` can be your best friend, `NSLog` misses you, call `NSLog` more often. :-) Seriously, use `NSLog`, LLDB and the stack trace.

Comment: Why are you using an array of dictionaries anyway?  All that code will do is overwrite the same text fields multiple times, which has no effect.  Why not just pass a single dictionary?

Comment: BTW - why are you using `valueForKey:` instead of `objectForKey:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Chris said, your `for` loop might not be what makes your code an infinite loop.

I'm used to add this code to know what is calling my functions. Just put it at the begin of your function `updateFieldsWithData:`

```
NSString *sourceString = [[NSThread callStackSymbols] objectAtIndex:1];
NSCharacterSet *separatorSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" -[]+?.,"];
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[sourceString  componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:separatorSet]];
[array removeObject:@""];

NSLog(@"Class caller = %@", [array objectAtIndex:3]);
NSLog(@"Function caller = %@", [array objectAtIndex:4]);
```